# Passing a string array to a function using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

So I am trying to a pass a char array into a function and print it out and then return the array back.

Below is my main function. I am doing Binary Search Trees however Im just stuck on passing a char array.

```
int main()
{
    BST tree = new_bst();
    int noRecords;
    int tfn;
    char name[10];
    char *test;

    FILE *fileptr;
    fileptr = fopen("welfare1.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fileptr, "%d", &noRecords);
    fscanf(fileptr, "%s", name);
    fscanf(fileptr, "%d", &tfn);

    insert_bst(&tree, tfn, &name);
}
```

And here is the insert BST function so far. I haven't implemented it yet as I can't pass the name field to my function, im using the printf as a test to see if it worked.

```
BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n, char *name)
{

    if (self == NULL)
    {
        TaxRecordPtr newRecord = new_record();


        self = malloc(sizeof *self);
        self->data = newRecord;
        self->left = self->right = NULL;

        printf("%c", name[0]);
}
```

Comment: ....and the problem is....?

Comment: `&name` is not a `char*`!  But plain `name` decays to one...

Comment: arrays are passed by reference only so, simply `insert_bst(&tree, tfn, name);` and `BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n, char name[])` should work for you

Comment: Using `insert_bst(&tree, tfn, name); and BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n, char name[])`

It steps through but the printf function fails and I get this

**Exception thrown at 0x0F63125C (ucrtbased.dll) in Assign1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000007C.**

Comment: You have mismatched parens in `insert_bst_node` and the name does not match the call to `insert_bst`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
insert_bst(&tree, tfn, &name);
```

to

```
insert_bst(&tree, tfn, name);
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-elemement array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call

```
insert_bst(&tree, tfn, name);
```

the expression `name` isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it "decays" to type `char *`, which matches the type of the argument in the function definition.

When you call

```
insert_bst(&tree, tfn, &name);
```

the expression `name` *is* the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion doesn't happen; instead, the type of the expression is `char (*)[10]`, or "pointer to 10-element array of `char`", which doesn't match the type of the argument in the function definition.

Answer (score -1):

A char array is equivalent to a pointer to char.
So when referencing a char array, the desired type would be a double pointer to char

```
BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n, char **name)
```

Anyway, there is no point to pass a pointer to the char array, you could just pass the char array itself

```
insert_bst(&tree, tfn, name);
```

You won't be passing the char array by value, since an array is equivalent to a pointer.

Comment: Neither the decayed type of `name` nor `&name` is a `char**`.

Comment: `&name` is a pointer to array, not a pointer to a char pointer. **Arrays and pointers are different animals** even is arrays can *decay* to pointer...